# GCM - registerID is empty immediately after register is complete

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I finally got the app working to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). But I have a problem. The moment right after the registration is complete, I want to get the registrationId. Except the registrationId is empty, unless I restart the app, then it gives back an value.

Basically what I want is to retrieve the registerId right after the registration is complete.

This is the code I am using:

```
checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

TextView mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

String regId = "";

if (!GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this))
{
    mDisplay.setText("registering");
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);

    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    String url = "localhost/Google-Cloud-Messaging-Server-Test/registration.php?regId=" + regId;

    Log.i(TAG, "registration url: " + url);
    HttpRequest httprequest = new HttpRequest(url);
}
else
{
    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    mDisplay.setText(regId);
    Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");

    GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
}
```

The problem is that after the code reaches this point:

```
regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
String url = "localhost/Google-Cloud-Messaging-Server-Test/registration.php?regId=" + regId;
```

the regId is empty. It should have a value, because the registration succeeds.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a possibility that it tries to get the registrationId while it actually is still going through the register process?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

EDIT: the manifest.xml content

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.codeglue.google.cloud.messaging.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<permission
    android:name="com.codeglue.google.cloud.messaging.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.codeglue.google.cloud.messaging.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.codeglue.google.cloud.messaging.test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you show us your manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

1. `GCMregistrar.register()` method sends `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER` Intent (asynchronously) to google (take look at [Registering for GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#registering) docs and GCMregistrar sources, especially on [register](https://code.google.com/r/sachinworldnet-pushnote/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java?spec=svn2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4&r=2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4#214) and [internalRegister](https://code.google.com/r/sachinworldnet-pushnote/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java?spec=svn2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4&r=2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4#220) methods).
2. Then Google handles your `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER` Intent and sends `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` Intent with registration ID as response.
3. Then when `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` intent will come from google (into response), broadcastReceiver (which is registrated to handle this type of Intents) will invoked, and only after that registration ID will be saved into `SharedPreferences`.

I remind that [getRegistrationId()](https://code.google.com/r/sachinworldnet-pushnote/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.java?spec=svn2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4&r=2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4#305) method gets ID from `SharedPreferences` of your device (not from google), which means that before you can get ID from `SharedPreferences` - first it should be saved there. (And ID saves there only when `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` comes from google). I'm not sure where exactly placed logics which saves ID into  `SharedPreferences` (i think the answer should be into GCMRegistrar [sources](https://code.google.com/r/sachinworldnet-pushnote/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/?r=2f8f3795e6e7ae45be1f8856fcd5047fe041ada4))

So. In your programm your `registrationID` string is empty because of:

1. you call `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId` method exactly after `GCMRegistrar.register` method. Keep in mind that `register` method sends intent to google asynchronously, which means that while you call `getRegistrationId` method there is no guaranty that responce from google with your ID is already recieved and your id is already saved into `SharedPreferences`.

If you want to catch the moment when `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` Intent comes from google - take look at `GCMIntentService`'s `onRegistered` method.

Answer (score 0):

please check the manifest.xml , so that you have add all uses-permission and receiver   correctly or not.

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission
    android:name="you_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="you_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

this receiver class must be in same package in which you have write down the code for registration

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="you_package_name" />
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I got all the permissions right, because when I restart the app, the regId has a value.